# request.json only returns string

Tags: python, json, flask, vue.js, axios

I use Axios and Flask to develop RESTful API.

But there is a problem about JSON data between Axios and Flask.

I cannot get JSON data from Axios by `request.json`.

I try a lot of ways, but nothing works.

Mostly, `request.json` will get `None`, and `request.data` will get:

```
b'------WebKitFormBoundaryNzW4jnyUkdEH3jsX\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="user"\r\n\r\nu\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryNzW4jnyUkdEH3jsX\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="pwd"\r\n\r\np\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryNzW4jnyUkdEH3jsX--\r\n'
```

After debugging, `request.json` can get the data now.

But it can only get `string`, not `json`.

Here is the code:

## Axios

```js
var config = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
axios.post('/api/user', {user: 'user', pwd: 'pwd'}, config)
.then(function(resp) {
    // ...
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // ...
});
```

## Flask

```
@app.route('/api/user', methods=['POST'])
def user():
    j = request.json
    print(j)
    print(type(j))
```

## Result

```
{"user": "user", "pwd": "pwd"}
class 'str'
```

How do I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Does `get_json()` work?

Comment: No, same as request.json

Comment: Looks like you sent form data instead of JSON

Comment: Yes, I thinks so. But how can I sent JSON from Axios?

Comment: I don't know... maybe try without the `config` and `Content-Type` header since Axios serializes data to JSON by default.

Comment: It didn't work too... T T

Comment: Strange. Do you have some global Axios config somewhere in the app?

Comment: No. I don't know how to set global Axios config...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like from Axios you somehow are sending your json as a string.
As a workaround, from the flask side you can transform the stringified json into dictionary.

```
import json

@app.route('/api/user', methods=['POST'])
def user():
    j = json.loads(request.json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using `get_json()` instead. According to flask docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json) it says to not use `json` but rather `get_json()`.